# How to configure SAML 2.0 in Tomcat to enable SSO to Azure AD

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2b

Need help with the plugin or any open source library that can be leveraged to configure SAML 2.0 in Tomcat to enable SSO to Azure AD. Here, Azure AD will act as an Identity Provider(IDP). If anyone can help with a reference document/URL that would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you try using a [search engine](https://dzone.com/articles/saml-single-sign-on-with-tomcat-and-picketlink)?

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java

Comment: Do you still need help on this issue? Any updates?